# How to know if sendto() with TCP Fast Open actually used Fast Open?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I write a TCP client on a Linux 3.15 machine, which is able to use TCP Fast Open:

```
        status = sendto(sd, (const void *) data, data_len, MSG_FASTOPEN,
                        (const struct sockaddr *) hostref->ai_addr,
                        sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        if (status < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "sendto: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "TFO connection successful to %s\n",
                    text_of(hostref->ai_addr));
```

Using tcpdump, I can check the sending of the TCP Fast Open option and that it does bypass the 3-way handshake (tested with Google's servers).

However, with servers which does *not* accept TCP fast open, sendto still succeeds, and the message "TFO connection successful" is displayed. Apparently, the Linux kernel code falls back to regular TCP if the server does not support TCP Fast Open (again, checked with tcpdump).

How to find out if my connection used TCP Fast Open or not?

Comment: If you really want to, you can use raw sockets to open up your TCP connection.

Comment: The point of sendto() is to *send the data*.  If you want that to be provisional on successfully fast-opening the connection then you'll have to roll your own.  But why do that?

Comment: Why do you care? If the message gets through to both kinds of servers, surely your work is finished?

Comment: Exactly. You don't need to know if TFO was used. The kernel knows, and it will deliver the data, either using TFO or not. You asked the kernel to send X data, so it will. You don't need to adjust your subsequent `send()`/`sendto()` calls to account for TFO. There is no difference on the receiving end, `recv()`/`recvfrom()` will return whatever data was initially received and cached by `accept()` when TFO is enabled on the server side.

Comment: I hate "why do you want to know?" comments. Verbose logging, curiosity and debugging are not good reasons anymore?

Answer (score 7):

By looking at the patch set that added TCP fast open in the linux kernel, you notice that it wasn't added any external indication that fast open was used.

You can indirectly notice certain cases where fast open was not used and certain cases where fast open was definitely used.

The case that you are sure fast open was not used is when the value of the TCPFastOpenActive counter was not incremented in /proc/net/netstat after a successful sendto() connection:

```
+   if (tcp_transmit_skb(sk, syn_data, 0, sk->sk_allocation) == 0) {
+       NET_INC_STATS(sock_net(sk), LINUX_MIB_TCPFASTOPENACTIVE);
+       goto done;
+   }
```

The case that you are sure fast open was used is when you have a non-blocking socket, you already have a fast open cookie and sendto() does not return EINPROGRESS:

> For non-blocking socket, it returns the number of bytes queued (and
>   transmitted in the SYN-data packet) if cookie is available. If cookie
>   is not available, it transmits a data-less SYN packet with Fast Open
>   cookie request option and returns -EINPROGRESS like connect().

For the remaining case, that is, you don't have a cookie, but you were able to connect and TCPFastOpenActive was incremented, you can't say if fast open was used (TCPFastOpenActive increment was caused by your fast open) or if fast open was not used (TCPFastOpenActive increment was not caused by your fast open).

http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.6#head-ac78950a7b57d92d5835642926f0e147c680b99c

http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=cf60af03ca4e71134206809ea892e49b92a88896

http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/diff/net/ipv4/tcp_output.c?id=783237e8daf13481ee234997cbbbb823872ac388

Comment: This all assumes that nobody else is doing it at the same time. If they are, all bets are off: the increment could be due to another process.

Comment: Read again. "you can't say if fast open was used (TCPFastOpenActive increment was caused by your fast open) or if fast open was not used (TCPFastOpenActive increment was not caused by your fast open)."