# Checking server for tcp fastopen support

Tags: tcp, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible, and if so how, to test if a server supports TCP_FASTOPEN?
Specifically, I would like to check if Google Cloud Storage supports it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to perform a TCP dump and check if the server accepted the upload through TFO as explained in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244536/how-to-know-if-sendto-with-tcp-fast-open-actually-used-fast-open).

You could try uploading the files through a simple [gsutil cp](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) with the gsutil to run a test and see if the server accepted TFO.